# Fitting text within parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been working on this for weeks and can't even seem to reproduce the problem in a consistent way.

I need to make sure the text in my buttons is as large as possible without extending outside of the parent div. I've tried 5-10 fitty/fitText type plug-ins and none of them are working properly, and the text either shrinks or expands way too big.

I've created this codepen to show the problem with it being too big:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/WNjRpOQ

I had to use an online link to jQuery and fitText. The weird thing is, if I copy the exact same code to JSfiddle, everything works perfectly:

https://jsfiddle.net/TheNomadicAspie/3yjw8kbt/7/

This is exactly how I want it to look, it's perfect. But when I run it in VS Code with a live server (Only difference being a local file instead of a link), it looks like the codepen and expands outside of the div:

[image]

I uploaded the fitText and jQuery links myself so I know they're the same version, and with the exact same code it doesn't work on Codepen or on my VS Code, but it does work on JS Fiddle. How can that be, and how can I make my code work the same way as it does on JS Fiddle?

Here's my code in case the Codepen or JS Fiddle changes.

```
<div id="screen" , class="screen">
        <div id="menu_bar" , class="menu-bar">
            <div id="logo" , class="logo">
                <img src="logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="title" , class="title">Title</div>
            <div id="menu_button" , class="menu-button">
                <img src="menu.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="display" , class="display">
            <div id="speech_bubble" , class="speech-bubble">
                <div id="logo_animation" , class="logo-animation"><img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/E0SE1bDv0sTbCH4p6V/giphy.gif?cid=790b761143fe1cebe2466c26bfb82fc6b178eb7ecad3874e&rid=giphy.gif"/></div>
                <div id="question" class="question resize">
                   <div id="question_text" class="question-text">
                    <span>This is some test text</span>
                   </div> 
                    </div>
                <div id="speech_bubble_middle_bar" class="speech-bubble-middle-bar">
                    <input type="text" id="input-text" class="input-text" />
                </div>
                <div id="speech_bubble_bottom_bar" class="speech-bubble-bottom-bar">
                    <div id="left" class="left-button-container">
                        <button id="left_button" class="button resize">Wow!</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right_button_container" class="right-button-container">
                        <button id="right_button" class="button resize">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bottom_bar" , class="bottom-bar">
                <div id="character" , class="character">
                </div>
                <div id="bottom_display" , class="bottom-display">
                    <div id="answers_display" , class="answers-display">
                        <div id="answer_container_1" , class="answer-button-1">
                            <div id="answer_checkbox_1" , class="checkbox">
                            </div>
                            <div id="answer_button_container_1" , class="answer-button-container">
                                <button id="answer_button_1" , class="button pushable resize">
                                    <span class="front">Super long button times four five six seven</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="answer_container_2" , class="answer-button-2">
                            <div id="answer_checkbox_2" , class="checkbox">
                            </div>
                            <div id="answer_container_2" , class="answer-button-container">
                                <button id="answer_button_2" , class="button pushable resize">
                                    <span class="front">Button 2</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="answer_container_3" , class="answer-button-3">
                            <div id="answer_checkbox_3" , class="checkbox">
                            </div>
                            <div id="answer_container_3" , class="answer-button-container">
                                <button id="answer_button_3" , class="button pushable resize">
                                    <span class="front">Button 3</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="answer_container_4" , class="answer-button-4">
                            <div id="answer_checkbox_4" , class="checkbox">
                            </div>
                            <div id="answer_container_4" , class="answer-button-container">
                                <button id="answer_button_4" , class="button pushable resize">
                                    <span class="front">Button 4</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="menu_display" , class="menu-display">
                        <div id="menu_container_1" , class="menu-button-1">
                            <div id="menu_button_container_1" , class="menu-button-container">
                                <button id="menu_button_1" , class="button resize">Restart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu_container_2" , class="menu-button-2">
                            <div id="menu_button_container_2" , class="menu-button-container">
                                <button id="menu_button_2" , class="button resize">Options</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu_container_3" , class="menu-button-3">
                            <div id="menu_button_container_3" , class="menu-button-container">
                                <button id="menu_button_3" , class="button resize">More Info</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu_container_4" , class="menu-button-4">
                            <div id="menu_button_container_4" , class="menu-button-container">
                                <button id="menu_button_4" , class="button resize">Log out</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://filebin.net/ykl05vxy49xx5vxp/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://filebin.net/ykl05vxy49xx5vxp/jquery.fittext.js"></script
```

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -mo-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #311049;
    font-size: 2vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.screen {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu-bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
    position: relative;
    height: 13.714%;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0%;
    text-align: center;
}

.logo {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.logo img {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 95%;
    max-width: 95%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.title {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    position: relative;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: hack;
    font-size: clamp(2vw, 8vw, 10vh);
    display: flex;
    top: 0%;
}

.menu-button {
    grid-column: 3/4;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu-button img {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.display {
    position: relative;
    height: 86.286%;
    width: 100vw;
}

.speech-bubble {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 60% 20% 20%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    height: 61.8%;
    width: 90vw;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 2em;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15vw;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 4em solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -2em;
    margin-bottom: -2em;
    z-index: -1;
}

.logo-animation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    display: none;
}

.logo-animation img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

.question {
    grid-rows: 1/2;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 3vh;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.question-text {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.speech-bubble-middle-bar {
    grid-rows: 2/3;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.input-text {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    border-radius: 2.5em;
    border: 0.25em solid black;
    padding: 1%; 
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.speech-bubble-bottom-bar {
    grid-rows: 3/4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.left-button-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 38.2%;
    left: 0%;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.left-button-container button {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.right-button-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 38.2%;
    right: 0%;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.right-button-container button {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.bottom-bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 38.2% 61.8%;
    position: relative;
    height: 38.2%;
    width: 100vw;
    bottom: 0%;
}

.character {
    grid-columns: 1/2;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('character.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: bottom;
    background-position-x: center;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-top: 3em;
}

.character img {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 80%;
    max-width: 90%;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
}

.bottom-display {
    grid-columns: 2/3;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 5vw;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.answers-display {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1%;
    height: 99%;
    max-height: 99%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(clamp( 28vw, 45vmin, 35vw ), 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows:1fr;
    height:100%;
    }

.menu-display {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows:1fr;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(clamp( 28vw, 45vmin, 35vw ), 1fr));
    height: 100%;
    gap: 1%;
    display: none;
}

.answer-button-1 {
    grid-rows: 1/2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    height: 98%;
}

.answer-button-2 {
    grid-rows: 2/3;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    height: 98%;
}

.answer-button-3 {
    grid-rows: 3/4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    height: 99%;
}

.answer-button-4 {
    grid-rows: 4/5;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    height: 99%;
}

.checkbox {
    grid-columns: 1/2;
    max-height: 90%;
    background-image: url('checkbox_unchecked.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: none;
}

.answer-button-container {
    grid-columns: 2/3;
    padding-left: 5%;
    height: 100%;
}

.answer-button-container button {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.menu-button-container button {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.menu-button-container {
    padding-left: 5%;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu-button-1 {
    grid-rows: 1/2;
    height: 98%;
}

.menu-button-2 {
    grid-rows: 2/3;
    height: 98%;
}

.menu-button-3 {
    grid-rows: 3/4;
    height: 99%;
}

.menu-button-4 {
    grid-rows: 4/5;
    height: 99%;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #311049; /*Button Color*/
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: hack;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.2em;
    box-shadow: 0.1em 0.2em black;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.button:hover:active {
    transition: 0.1s;
    box-shadow: 0.01em 0.02em black;
    transform: translate(0.05em, 0.1em);
}
.button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0.06em 0.12em black;
    transform: translate(-0.01em, -0.02em);
}

.left-btn::after {
    display: block;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    line-height: 0.5em;
    content: "\2190";
}

.right-btn::after {
    display: block;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    line-height: 0.5em;
    content: "\2192";
}
```

```
const left_button = document.getElementById('left_button')
const right_button = document.getElementById('right_button')
const answer_button_1 = document.getElementById('answer_button_1')
const answer_button_2 = document.getElementById('answer_button_2')
const answer_button_3 = document.getElementById('answer_button_3')
const answer_button_4 = document.getElementById('answer_button_4')

var answer_button_dict = {
    '1': answer_button_1,
    '2': answer_button_2,
    '3': answer_button_3,
    '4': answer_button_4,
    'left': left_button,
    'right': right_button
}

Object.values(answer_button_dict).forEach(button => {
    jQuery(button).fitText()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your fitting script (it's not working in your JS fiddle anyway, works just on codepen), remove font-size from `.left-button-container button` and `.right-button-container button`, set `.button` from `font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);` to `font-size: clamp(1rem, 6vh, 3rem);`

You are trying to rely on page width for button width and to rely on page height for button and its text height - just test more screen sizes and play with `font-size: clamp` part

Comment: Thanks for the tip about vh instead of vw, it works a lot better now. But I still can't get it to stay within the constraints of the div on all tested devices. It works pretty well on my phone and computer, but for example if I go to Chrome's developer view and set it to iPhone Max, this happens.

https://imgur.com/a/YExgFob

Is there really no way to set the font size to the maximize possible without expanding past the horizontal constraints of the div? It seems like it should be a really simple thing to do but I've spent 30+ hours just trying to fix my button font size.

Comment: Everyone just says to adjust the clamp settings, but how well that stays within the div depends on the size of the screen.

Comment: I did clamp(1rem, 4.5vh, 3rem) in that image, but I've tried tons of combinations using just vh, just rem, etc.... I have a lot of different length text that will go in the buttons, so I need something that I can change dynamically depending on the text in the div.

Comment: @TheNomadicAspie try to add css min based on width. `font-size: min(7vw, clamp(1rem, 4.5vh, 3rem));` 
https://codepen.io/FalloWingS/pen/yLbgXjB